# Different Page Sizes for Processes

Tags: operating-system, frame, mmu

As part of the virtual to physical address conversion, for each process a table of mappings between virtual to physical addresses is stored. If a process is scheduled next the content of the page table is loaded into the MMU.

1) Where is the page table for each process stored? As part of the process control block?

2) Does the page table contain entries for not allocated memory so a segfault can be detected (more easily)?

3) Is it possible (and used in any known relevant OS) that one process does have multiple page frame sizes? Especially if question 2 is true it is very convenient to map huge page tables to non existing memory to keep the page table as small as possible. It will still allow high precision in mapping smaller frames to the memory to keep external (and internal) fragmentation as small as possible? This of course requires an extra field storing the frame size for each entry. Please point out the reason(s) if my "idea" cannot exist.

Answer (score 1):

1)  They could be, but most OS's have a notion of an address space which a process is attached to.  The address space typically contains a description of the sorts of mappings that have been established, and pointers to the page structure(s).  If you consider the operation of exec(2), at a certain level of abstraction it merely involves creating a new address space, populating it, then attaching the process to it.   Once the operation is known to succeed, the old address space can simply be discarded.

2)  It depends upon the mmu architecture of the machine.  In a forward mapped arrangement (x86, armv[78]), the page tables form a sort of tree structure, but instead of having the conventional 2 or 3 items per node, there are hundreds or thousands of them.   The x86-classic has a 2 level structure, where each of the 1024 entries in the first level points to a pagetable which covers 2^20 bytes of address space.  Invalid entries, either at the inner or leaf level, can represent unmapped space; so in x86-classic, if you have a very small address space, you only need a root table, and a single leaf level table.

3)  Yes, multiple page size has been supported by most OSes since the early 2000s.  Again, in forward mapped ones, each of the levels of the tree can be replaced by a single large page for the same address space as that table level.   x86-classic only had one size; later editions supported many more.

3a) There is no need to use large pages to do this -- simply having an invalid page table is sufficient.   In x86-classic, the least significant bit of the page table/descriptor entry indicates the validity of the entry.

Your idea exists.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Where is the page table for each process stored? As part of the process control block?

Usually it's not "a page table". For some CPUs there's only TLB entries (Translation Lookaside Buffer entries - like a cache of what the translations are) where software has to handle "TLB miss" by loading whatever it feels like into the TLB itself, and where the OS might not use tables at all (e.g. could use "list of arbitrary length zones"). For some CPUs it's a hierarchy of multiple levels (e.g. for modern 64-bit 80x86 there's 4 levels); and in this case some of the levels may be in physical memory and some may be in swap space or somewhere else and some may be generated as needed from other data (a little bit like it would've been for "software handling of TLB miss"). In any case, if each process has its own virtual address space (e.g. and it's not some kind of "single-address space shared by many processes" scheme) its likely that the process control block (directly or indirectly) contains a reference to whatever the OS uses (e.g. maybe a single "physical address for the highest level page table", but maybe a virtual address of a "list of arbitrary length zones" and maybe anything else).

> 2) Does the page table contain entries for not allocated memory so a segfault can be detected (more easily)?

If there are page tables then there must be a way to indicate "page not present", where "page not present" may mean that the memory isn't allocated but could also mean that the (virtual) memory was allocated but the entry for it hasn't been set (either because OS is generating the tables on demand, or because the actual data is in swap space, or...).

> 3) Is it possible (and used in any known relevant OS) that one process does have multiple page frame sizes?

Yes. It's relatively common for 64-bit 80x86 where there's 4 KiB pages, 2 MiB (or 4 MiB) "large pages" (plus maybe 1 GiB "huge pages"); and done to reduce the chance of TLB misses (while also reducing memory consumed by page tables). Note that this is mostly an artifact of having multiple levels of page tables - an entry in a higher level table can say "this entry is a large page" or it can say "this entry is a lower level page table that might contain smaller pages". Note that in this case it's not "multiple page sizes in the same table", but is "fixed page size for each level".

> Especially if question 2 is true it is very convenient to map huge page tables to non existing memory to keep the page table as small as possible. It will still allow high precision in mapping smaller frames to the memory to keep external (and internal) fragmentation as small as possible? This of course requires an extra field storing the frame size for each entry. Please point out the reason(s) if my "idea" cannot exist.

Converting a virtual address into a physical address (or some kind of fault to indicate the translation doesn't exist) needs to be very fast (because it happens extremely often). When you have "fixed page size for each level" it means you can extract some bits of the virtual address and use them as the index into the table; which is fast.

When you have "multiple page sizes in the same table" there's 2 options. The first option is to duplicate entries in the page table so that you can still extract some bits of the virtual address and use them as the index into the table; which (apart from minor differences in the way TLBs are managed - e.g. auto-detecting adjacent translations vs. being manually told) is effectively identical to not bothering at all; but there are some CPUs (ARM I think) that do this.

The other alternative is searching multiple entries in the page table to find the right entry, where the cost of searching reduces performance. I don't know of any CPU that supports this - performance is too important.